# c# add unmanaged dll to project

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, unmanaged

I have  unmanaged dll that I do from my c# `dllImport` and call to functions from this dll.

What i done now is to copy this dll to my Realese and Debuge folders , and dllImport i call to this dll without any path.

What is the right way?

How can I add this unmanaged dll to my project that is automaticly will be in my realsae and debug folders. (  I can't wimple done add refernce with this dll because it unmanaged dll ).

And witch path should I write on the path on dllImport.

What is the right way?

Comment: Project > Add Existing Item > select the DLL.  Set its Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy if newer".  Check for typing mistakes.  Done.

Comment: @HansPassant this is he right way? with path should I write on dllImport?   And how i do "Set its Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy if newer". "???

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean  "Set its Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy if newer". " ??

Comment: Do *not* set a path, the name is enough.  Windows always looks first in the same directory as the EXE.  If you don't know how to use the Properties window then consider to try right-clicking the added file and select Properties.

Answer (score 0):

" **copy this dll to my Realese and Debuge folders**" works. you may try post build (in native c++ project) or pre build (in C# project)

[image]

[image]